# Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked. See sulogin (8) man page for more details (fedora-dualboot)

Tags: fedora, root

After manual and automated moves in privacy issues with some tools without being familiar with more specific things, the specific issue was created after a restart.Meanwhile after restarting windows because I'm running on my dualboot system, I get a black screen that says grub minimal bash-like and doesn't get into any mode.and it didn't work, but after I put fedora on the usb to fix the problem or in the worst case to reformat, I get this particular error on the usb and I'm stuck without being able to do anything.Meanwhile I used the usb on another pc and it works fine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRXBF.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.